# How to handle the request in the electron app (capture request, serve custom response)

Tags: electron, webrequest

I want to handle any API requests from the web app wrapped in the electron app. My intention was to keep the same API calls that web app delivered over the net will stay the same as when delivered as standalone electron app. In the latter I would capture API requests and serve responses created locally. Is it possible? I'm looking into `WebRequest` callbacks available through `session.defaultSession.webRequest` e.g. `session.defaultSession.webRequest.onResponseStarted`

**Edit 02/01/2020**
I've found also to use the `Protocol`API but then I would have to modify my API calls which I want to intercept to use custom protocol when within electron wrapper which is not what I want (intercept request and serve custom response on electron).

Answer (score 0):

Your web app will work 100%(*) the same in Electron as it does without. The (*) is the caveat that throwing the production flag on your web app may come with other side effects, and that may confuse things.

Just because Electron comes with its own native way to handle certain things, doesn't mean Electron will prevent you from doing things the way you've been doing thus far.

For example I'm doing all my client-server action via JQuery's `.ajax()` method and Sails.js's MVC action handlers. Electron hasn't interfered at all.

However, if you *want* Electron to interfere, you can do that. See the [WebRequest part of the Electron API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request). In particular the first method on the page, `onBeforeRequest`, seems relevant to the requirement mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I DO want electron to interfere with the handling requests as I want to intercept, read and give response not from the remote resource but from the local resource (but want to keep the same means via API request).